# What data structure to use?

Tags: c++, c, data-structures

I need a data structure with the following properties:

- Access to elements must be very fast
- Elements, that are not added, shouldn't take memory (as ideal, size of empty structure near to zero)
- Each element has two integer coordinates (x,y) (access to elements only by them)
- Max count of elements known at creation time (over 10^3)
- Element contains few float values

It would be good if you also directed to an implementation of this structure in C or C++.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: Choose your language. There is no such thing as C/C++, and the implementations for these 2 languages would be very different.

Comment: @R.. your point is taken, but that argument is REALLY tired. I refer to C/C++ all the time. Why? Because our packages usually end up being C++ wrappers around C packages. I don't think anybody is horribly offended, save for the purists in both camps who have the luxury of picking one language or the other.

Comment: @San Jacinto: if the questioner is in the same situation as you, then he should specify C, and not C++. The simple reason is that based on the brief (in particular, no requirement to iterate along either rows or columns), the easy C++ solution to this is probably `boost::unordered_map<pair<int,int>,Element>`. I don't consider it particularly "purist" or "luxurious" to write C++ and use common C++ libraries, so a solution that has to work in both is more or less a C solution.

Comment: @Steve my point was more that "I can accept a package or solution in either form" since our code already has a part that is C thinly-wrapped in C++, and some straight C++ for most of it. It doesn't have to work in _both_, it has to work for _me_. The purists take this cute little "there is no C/C++ language", but I'd like them to explain that to the original writers for the tools like MFC, Qt, and the like. At some point, most C++ programmers end up wrapping C code in C++. That's all I'm saying. Not that the two languages are primarily the same.

Comment: @San: Your comment is irrelevant to my point. Since OP asked for an *implementation* and not just the conceptual data structure/algorithms, the choice of C versus C++ matters *a lot*. A good C++ implementation would make heavy use of classes (and probably existing STL stuff), and would not be possible to use in a C program. A C implementation would use structures and pointers and (non-member) functions, which would be horrid to use in a C++ program. Surely you could wrap this implementation in a C++ class, but it would be a lot cleaner and more efficient to just use the right language.

Comment: @R.. no doubt, you are correct in either case. But if I'm the OP, I'm not going to look a gift horse in the mouth. If you provide a C implementation, I'd wrap it with a class interface. If you provide a C++ implementation, I'd just use it. To bring up the old "there is no such thing as C/C++" is rather pedantic for such a situation. Save it for code reviews where a developer is using C-style in place of C++ mechanisms. That's all I'm saying, not that you're wrong in your point.

Comment: @San Jacinto:  There is indeed no such language as C/C++.  If you were to want a solution, you could specify it needed to be in C, or in C++, or that you could use either.  There is no generally accepted and useful definition of C/C++ "C code with C++ wrappers" would be useful, if generally accepted), and it's usually a sign of sloppy thinking.

Comment: do you need to remove elements? will elements be added one at a time or in batches? what's the range of your `x,y` coordinates?

Comment: @David we'll just have to agree to disagree. I think it's a pedantic cliche that people throw around to sound like their favorite C++ author. You don't. That pretty much draws the line, doesn't it? :)

Comment: @San: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, "C/C++" would be a perfectly good way of saying "C or C++", since "/" is commonly used to mean "or". Except that "C/C++" is also commonly used to mean the mythical combined language, as when people say things like, "how big is an int in C/C++?" Hence the ambiguity, and hence the snark. Btw, I misunderstood your case because I thought you (hypothetically) would want to use the structure *from* your package that's written in C and wrapped in C++, and hence a C solution would be required. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this out - you could alter the element type to `float` if this does everything you want.

[Concise Sparse Matrix Package in C](http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/c_src/csparse/csparse.html)

For C++ you could use `Boost.uBLAS` - sparse_matrix details [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm).

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for a [sparse matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) ?

Comment: Good point. Except that, if the OP's remark "over 10^3" really means "a few thousand", I'd recommend a simple 2-d array.

Answer (score 1):

If your X and Y are relatively small then a two dimensional array of pointers would work. 10000 pointers would be 40K in 32 bit code.

Comment: Even in 64 bit mode, he can used 32 bit indexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
typdef ElementAccessor std::pair<int, int>;

struct Element
{
  float f1;
  float f2;
  //etc.

};

std::map< ElementAccessor, Element > myElementMap;
```

You can now use this map as a matrix. ElementAccessor refers to x,y. Just make sure to see if the element exists in the map before you try to access it, or one is created by default.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/pair/
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/find/

edit: the template brackets are showing up for the map. the map key type is ElementAccessor, the value is Element. Also, for the pair, the templating is int, int.

Comment: Accesss to these elements is logarithmic time. So if you put 1 million elements in the map, it still would not take many operations to access your data. Not a constant-time array dereference, but a big space-saver.

Comment: markup fixed. There is (or used to be, I didn't check) an irritating bug in SO that code indentation doesn't work on the first line, hence the nbsp.